# How do you get a Bixby confirmation view to show up?

Tags: bixby

I've spent a long time going over documentation but have not been able to get a confirmation view to show up before running my action. What are the steps to adding a confirmation view to a capsule?

I have an action called `Evaluate` and an address input that i automatically pull from the user's profile. I would like to confirm this address before running `Evaluate` in case the user wants to use a different address

Here's what I have done:

1) import viv.common in capsule.bxb:

```
import (viv.common) {
      as (common)
      version (3.30.0)
    }
```

2) add confirm/by statement to Evaluate action:

```
confirm {
    by (common.Confirmation)
  }
```

3) add a confirmation view that will match on the evaluate action:

```
confirmation-view {
    match: common.Confirmation {
      confirming {Evaluate (action) }
    }
    mode (PositiveEmphasis)
    message ("Is this the correct address?")

    render {
      layout {
        section {
          content{
            paragraph {
              style (Title_XS)
              value {
                template (
                "#{value(action.address)}}?"
                )
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    confirm-options {        
        label ("Yes")
    }
    abort-options {
        label ("Try another Address")
        on-abort {
            intent {
              goal: InputAddress
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping that would do it, but I think i'm missing something else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been looking into this and my guess is that **it doesn't work with a `Calculation` action (or `Constructor` action), you need a transaction action**, based on the following sentence in the [confirmation-view documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/confirmation-view):

> There must be a corresponding transactional action asking for confirmation with the confirm key.

Take a look at the sample capsule [capsule-sample-bank](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-bank). Committing a transfer prompts the user for Confirmation. They use two confirmation prompts:

- The first one is done before to prompt the user to confirm before evaluating `CreateTransfer` and results in a `Transfer` model. This is the one you're looking for.
- The second one is done using `transaction-support` and a `match { Transfer }` to match the output of the first one and starts a new intent on `CommitTransfer` upon user confirmation.

The relevant files in the folder structure are:

```
+-- models/
|  +-- actions/
|  |  +-- CreateTransfer.model.bxb
+-- resources/
|  +-- base/
|  |  +-- dialog/
|  |  |  +-- CreateTransfer_Confirmation.dialog.bxb
|  |  |  +-- Transfer_Result.dialog.bxb
|  |  +-- transactions/
|  |  |  +-- precommit.transaction.bxb
|  |  +-- views/
|  |  |  +-- CreateTransfer_Confirmation.view.bxb
```

**Maybe someone from the Bixby developer team can expand this answer. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be possible to use a confirmation on a `Calculation` action.**

Comment: Great answer! In addition you can check the https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-shirt example. It has Confirmation.view.bxb modeled with on-click action. Different action type is to help Bixby plan routes internally. Calculation is, well, simple calculation.

Comment: Thanks @BixbyDevSupport-Tokonyan for the answer. Is it possible to somehow implement a Confirmation on a `Calculation` or `Constructor` action?

Comment: You can try, but just like C with pointer has index out of range, at your own risk. It might work one day, might get a complete meltdown the other day.